# Add percent symbol to label on y axis in StackedColumn100

Tags: c#, charts, series

How do I format the Y axis label so it includes % symbol when using StackedColumn100?

I am using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series charts.

here is my method for defining the chart look and feel (so far)...

```
private Series SetSeriesStyleStackedColumnPercentage(string sessionname, string color)
{
    Series series = new Series(sessionname);

    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100;
    series.Color = Color.FromArgb(byte.Parse(color.Split(',')[0]),
                                byte.Parse(color.Split(',')[1]),
                                byte.Parse(color.Split(',')[2]),
                                byte.Parse(color.Split(',')[3]));
    series.BorderWidth = 1;
    series.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0);
    series.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
    series.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
    return series;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic needed, just **escape** the percent character:

```
  chart1.ChartAreas[yourCharArea].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "###0\\%";
```

or

```
  chart1.ChartAreas[yourCharArea].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "###0.0\\%";
```

or whatever numeric formatting you need..

Comment: Well, I think the magic exists - its in the form of knowing what object to manipulate!  Your example worked flawlessly - I wasn't sure if I needed to modify the series or the chart.  Thanks for the answer - spot on!